# CGAffineTransform problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have a UIImageView that I applied a:

```
CGAffineTransformConcat(scaleTransform, rotateTransform);
```

Now I need to get the **actual scale value** and **rotation degrees**. I can get the rotation degrees, but the problem comes when getting the **scale value**. The scale value I get is not the right one, unless I rotate the view to 0.0;

I think this is happening because the matrix is now **multiplied** (scale * rotation).

Any ideas on how to get the right scale value?

Comment: please post answers as answers. not as part of the question.

Comment: I have no enough points to solve me own questions.

Comment: oh, I wasnt aware, that u have to have a certain amount of reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved me problem.

To get the Angle:

`float angle = atan2(imageView.transform.b, imageView.transform.a);`

The scale transform applied to the imageView was **uniform**, so to get the Scale Value:

```
CATransform3D localScaleTransform = [(CALayer *)[imageView.layer presentationLayer] transform];
float scale = sqrt(pow(localScaleTransform.m11, 2) + pow(localScaleTransform.m12, 2));
```

If you applied different scale values follow this:

scaleInX = sqrt(M11^2 + M12^2)

scaleInY = sqrt(M21^2 + M22^2)